# How to find active days worked on a project

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to create days dynamically for a month with the inputs month and year.
I have a project table which saves project start date and end date. 
I also have employees who can work in many projects.

The scenario which i have to find is as below

if my inputs are year=2015 and month=04

```
===============================================
Empname     01          02           03 ---  31
===============================================
 emp1       Active   project end
===============================================
```

I have to find whether an employee is active related to the 
particular day. How do I do this?

Comment: So you have a project table with a start end.  But from `emp1 Active project end`, I cannot tell what exactly you record for employee activity . Could you clarify?

Comment: Yeah..for employee 1 i have to find whether he is active or project ends on the day 01/04/2015 as same for the next 31 days..if the project ends on 01/04/2015 then for 02/04/2015 i have to find is there any project started if started i have to display as active otherwise i have to display as N/A ..

Answer (score 0):

I have revised the example to hopefully be close to what it sounds like you are trying to achieve (very unsure).  The whole thing is also available at this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f209a/7.

```
CREATE TABLE employee_active_on_project
(
    EmpName varchar(50),
    ProjectName varchar(50),
    StartOfProject datetime,
    EndOfProject datetime
);

CREATE Table employee
(
    EmpName varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE employee_projects
(
    ProjectName varchar(50),
    EmpName varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE result
(
    EmpName varchar(50),
    ProjectName varchar(50),
    IsActive int,
    DayOfMon int
);

insert into employee_active_on_project select 'john', 'projectx', '2015-04-02','2015-04-05'; 
insert into employee_active_on_project select 'john', 'projectx', '2015-04-09','2015-04-25';
insert into employee_active_on_project select 'john', 'projecty', '2015-04-06','2015-04-07';
insert into employee_active_on_project select 'jane', 'projectz', '2015-04-01','2015-04-27';
insert into employee select 'john';
insert into employee select 'jane';
insert into employee_projects select 'projectx', 'john';
insert into employee_projects select 'projecty', 'john';
insert into employee_projects select 'projectx', 'john';
insert into employee_projects select 'projectz', 'jane';

DECLARE @month int
DECLARE @year int
DECLARE @firstDay datetime
DECLARE @lastDay datetime
SET @month = 4
SET @year = 2015
SET @firstDay = DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,1)
SET @lastDay = DateAdd(day,-1,Dateadd(month,1,@firstDay))

;WITH CTE( oneDay, DayOfMon) as
(
  SELECT @firstDay as oneDay, 1 as DayOfMon
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dateadd(day, 1, oneDay), DayOfMon + 1 FROM CTE
  where dateadd(day, 1, oneDay) <= @lastDay
)
insert into result
SELECT
    emp.EmpName,
    ep.ProjectName,
    CASE WHEN e.EmpName IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsActive,
    DayOfMon
FROM Employee emp
INNER JOIN employee_projects ep on ep.EmpName = emp.EmpName
INNER JOIN cte on 1=1
LEFT JOIN employee_active_on_project e on cte.oneDay between e.StartOfProject and e.EndOfProject and emp.EmpName = e.EmpName and e.ProjectName =  ep.ProjectName
GROUP BY emp.EmpName,ep.projectName,CASE WHEN e.EmpName IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,DayOfMon

SELECT projectname,EmpName
[1],  [2],  [3],  [4],
[5],  [6],  [7],  [8],
[9],  [10], [11], [12],
[13], [14], [15], [16],
[17], [18], [19], [20],
[21], [22], [23], [24],
[25], [26], [27], [28],
[29], [30],[31]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        EmpName,
        ProjectName,
        IsActive,
        DayOfMon
    FROM result
) 
as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
SUM(isactive)
For DayOfMon in ([1], [2], [3], [4],
                [5], [6], [7], [8],
                [9], [10], [11], [12],
                [13], [14], [15], [16],
                [17], [18], [19], [20],
                [21], [22], [23], [24],
                [25], [26], [27], [28],
                [29],[30],[31])
) as PivotTable;
```

This gives output of only (showing half of month for space reasons):

```
+-------------+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| projectname | EmpName | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
+-------------+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| projectx    | john    | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
| projecty    | john    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
| projectz    | jane    | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
+-------------+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Yeah creating dates dynamically is not a problem..
   
let me explain it clearly

i need to write a stored procedure with the inputs month and year.

i have a project table which saves project start date and end date for 

each employee.eg : emp1- start date is 02/04/2015 and end date is 

10/04/2015 .


My output should contain columns employee id,01/04/2015,02/04/2015 

as like  upto 31/04/2015..

The Employee id column value- Emp1 

For 01/04/2015 column value-  N/A -because No project he has on 01/04/2015

Comment: CREATE TABLE employee_active_on_proj 
 (
  EmpName varchar(50),
  ProjectName varchar(50),
                StartofProject datetime
  EndOfProject datetime
 );

And here is one row of data

 insert into employee_active_on_proj select 'john', 'projectx', '2015-04-02','2015-04-05';
        insert into employee_active_on_proj select 'john', 'projectx', '2015-04-09','2015-04-25'


This is the real data.

Comment: Ok, I've completely updated stuff using your definition of the employee_active_on_project table.

Comment: @user2396746 - please add the table definition and your expected output in the question itself by editing the question with proper formatting. avoid adding details in comments

Comment: @DWright - based on the comments above you might have to change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` followed by a `PIVOT`

Comment: Thanks for the help clarifying. Going to sleep now, but will look in the morning.